# How do I make a new column every 4 elements in a row excel file?

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

I am trying to take many rows of excel files and parse them. I have multiple rows of 60 numbers. I would like to make a new stack or row every 4 numbers for every single row. I know this is confusing, an example would be:

```
input from excel 0.282836353 0.287834898 0.284861334 0.284880417 0.242768564 0.241888021    0.240441747 0.244627766 0.245007869 0.244790578 0.243485108 0.244743911 0.267488959 0.264294548 0.267708093 0.268158158

output: 0.282836353 0.287834898 0.284861334 0.284880417 
        0.242768564 0.241888021 0.240441747 0.244627766 
        0.245007869 0.244790578 0.243485108 0.244743911
        0.267488959 0.264294548 0.267708093 0.268158158
```

This is what I currently have tried:

```
import openpyxl
excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook("nameoffile.xlsx")
sheet = excelFile["Sheet1"]
nRows = sheet.max_row
nCols = sheet.max_column
r = 2
groups = 4 # how many to be grouped together
parsedList = []

while r <= nRows:
    rList,rListSum = [],[]
    x = 0
    c = 2
    while c <= nCols:
        if x < groups:
            cell = sheet.cell(row=r,column=c)
            rList.append(cell.value)
        x += 1
        if x == groups:
            rListSum.append(rList)  
    c += 1
    parsedList.append(rListSum)
r += 1
```

my current output is nothing. something seems to be wrong with my loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "multiple rows of 60 numbers" in the question is not clear.
Does each row have a string of 60 numbers (e.g. "0.1 0.2 0.3 ...") or 60 columns (e.g. A1, B1, ...)?

I assumed the latter one and you can simply do what you want by using `NumPy` and `Pandas`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,60))
```

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
0   0.609861    0.778792    0.223185    0.945089    0.630081    0.629745    0.893291    0.557107    0.044485    0.267008    ... 0.423123    0.236365    0.216665    0.173979    0.436419    0.206685    0.188097    0.042587    0.316459    0.252943
1   0.451599    0.234676    0.540550    0.576964    0.067314    0.180313    0.952212    0.725722    0.368086    0.351682    ... 0.209218    0.284543    0.504832    0.306373    0.830000    0.878597    0.549021    0.430474    0.162942    0.194625
2   0.346460    0.803657    0.270074    0.375594    0.080673    0.051869    0.119898    0.632888    0.497251    0.689102    ... 0.586911    0.725564    0.662852    0.814569    0.753149    0.363969    0.811467    0.144431    0.523725    0.725145
3   0.846687    0.488381    0.803212    0.405574    0.137206    0.963724    0.200077    0.576446    0.449057    0.125634    ... 0.295565    0.153730    0.259037    0.725119    0.427521    0.750190    0.222516    0.960042    0.786858    0.446018
4   0.563980    0.809230    0.420195    0.776374    0.506152    0.429394    0.802265    0.261096    0.924650    0.778620    ... 0.282234    0.333429    0.714918    0.404162    0.730436    0.939195    0.657210    0.368771    0.096418    0.189417
```

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 4))
```

```
    0   1   2   3
0   0.609861    0.778792    0.223185    0.945089
1   0.630081    0.629745    0.893291    0.557107
2   0.044485    0.267008    0.433519    0.093443
3   0.057903    0.786750    0.474591    0.579831
4   0.491986    0.686017    0.930706    0.144237
... ... ... ... ...
70  0.958695    0.789661    0.835077    0.146602
71  0.936193    0.436480    0.558998    0.770272
72  0.411825    0.388468    0.282234    0.333429
73  0.714918    0.404162    0.730436    0.939195
74  0.657210    0.368771    0.096418    0.189417
```

Comment: Yes it would be 60 columns exactly the output you have provided. I actually already had it in a pandas data frame so this would make it incredibly easy

Answer (score 0):

Below code has the same output as @J.Choi

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(df).reshape(-1, 4))
```

However it is less efficient:

[image]

Comment: `np.array(df)` is much slower than `df.to_numpy()`, especially for a large dataset. For `np.random.rand(5000,60)`, the time difference is tested as approximately 290x. Therefore, I strongly don't recommend to use `np.array(df)`.

Comment: yea, agree.. thanks for highlighting!